# Swift Parsing Error/Cast Exception

Tags: json, parsing, swift, casting

I am trying to parse JSON in swift. Earlier in my program it works just fine when I say

```
func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
    var err: NSError
    // throwing an error on the line below (can't figure out where the error message is)
    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

    println(jsonResult.valueForKey("results")?.valueForKey("geometry")?.valueForKey("location")?.valueForKey("lat"))

    if(jsonResult.valueForKey("status") as String == "OK"){
        var nearestLat = jsonResult.valueForKey("results")?.valueForKey("geometry")?.valueForKey("location")?.valueForKey("lat") as [CLLocationDegrees]
        var nearestLong = jsonResult.valueForKey("results")?.valueForKey("geometry")?.valueForKey("location")?.valueForKey("lng") as [CLLocationDegrees]
        var openStatus = jsonResult.valueForKey("results")?.valueForKey("opening_hours")?.valueForKey("open_now") as [Int]
        var address = jsonResult.valueForKey("results")?.valueForKey("vicinity") as [String]
        var name = jsonResult.valueForKey("results")?.valueForKey("name") as [String]

        var boolOpen = Bool(openStatus[0])

        var nearestChipotle = NearestRestaurant(name: name[0], lat: nearestLat[0], long: nearestLong[0], address: address[0], open: boolOpen)

        println(nearestChipotle.milesToRestuarant(self.latitude, fromLong: self.longitude))
//            
//            println(nearestLat[0])
//            println(nearestLong[0])
//            println(boolOpen)
//            println(address[0])
//            println(name[0])

    }

    else if jsonResult.valueForKey("status") as String == "ZERO_RESULTS"{
        println("NO CHIPOTLE!")
    }
```

Doesn't work

```
if(jsonResult.valueForKey("status") as String == "OK"){

        println(jsonResult.valueForKey("rows")?.valueForKey("elements")?.valueForKey("distance")?.valueForKey("text") as String)
       //var metersTo = jsonResult.valueForKey("rows")?.valueForKey("elements")?.valueForKey("distance")?.valueForKey("value") as String
        //println(metersTo)
       //self.distanceTo = metersToMiles()
       //println(self.distanceTo)
       //self.timeTo = jsonResult.valueForKey("rows")?.valueForKey("elements")?.valueForKey("duration")?.valueForKey("text") as String

        //println(metersTo)
        //println(self.timeTo)
    }

    else if jsonResult.valueForKey("status") as String == "ZERO_RESULTS"{
        println("NO DISTANCE COMPUTED!")
    }
```

but when I try this same approach later in the program, I am getting this error
[image: Some sort of casting error]

[image]

Caused by this code[image]

Here is what my output looks like. It looks like that the second JSON I am getting won't cast properly because of extra '(' ')' parentheses. 
[image: Second set of parentheses may be causing the error]

Any way to dispose of these parentheses or what caused them?

Both JSON info is coming from Google API

Comment: Please add your *real* code (`as [Int}` would not compile!) and *not* as a screenshot. – If you have a deeply chained expression with an unexpected result, why don't you split it into separate successive assignments and inspect each intermediate result? Then you can see where it does not work as expected.

Comment: There is the full code.